# Setup a method to return the return value of a function passed as an argument

Tags: c#, moq

I have:

```
public T MethodNameHere<T>(Func<T> func)
{
  return func.Invoke();
}
```

How do I setup a mock for that method. Something along the lines of:

```
this.mockService.Setup(a => a.MethodNameHere(It.IsAny<Func<Guid>>())).Returns(...?...);
```

How do I `Returns` whatever the `Func` has returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the passed argument in the `Returns` delegate and invoke that

```
this.mockService
    .Setup(_ => _.MethodNameHere(It.IsAny<Func<Guid>>()))
    .Returns((Func<Guid> func) => func());
```

Or

```
this.mockService
    .Setup(_ => _.MethodNameHere(It.IsAny<Func<Guid>>()))
    .Returns((Func<Guid> func) => func.Invoke());
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

```
// access invocation arguments when returning a value
mock.Setup(x => x.DoSomethingStringy(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns((string s) => s.ToLower());
// Multiple parameters overloads available
```

Comment: Oh, argument matching in the `Returns` statement, gotcha.

Comment: @HristoYankov An equivalent way to call this generic overload of `.Returns` is to give the type parameter explicitly, so: `.Returns<Func<Guid>>(func => func())`